# Unable to start Apache Superset due to failed PostgresDB connection using Docker

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, apache-superset

I am trying to install Superset using Docker. However, following the instructions, I am encountering an issue where the database connection is refused. I check the logs, the container responsible for database service is up and running but when I checked its logs, I see the following FATAL message:

```
2020-09-08 17:19:36.863 UTC [33] FATAL:  database "test" does not exist
```

[This](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#start-with-docker) is how I attempt to install Superset.

Following is the error I face when I run the command, `sudo docker-compose up`:

```
superset_app             | ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:DB Creation and initialization failed: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No route to host
superset_app             |  Is the server running on host "db" (172.18.0.3) and accepting
superset_app             |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
superset_app             | 
superset_app             | (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

The same error appears in other services as well.

[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/docker-compose.yml):

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
x-superset-build: &superset-build
  args:
    NPM_BUILD_CMD: build-dev
  context: ./
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
  - db
  - redis
x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
  # /app/pythonpath_docker will be appended to the PYTHONPATH in the final container
  - ./docker/docker-init.sh:/app/docker-init.sh
  - ./docker/pythonpath_dev:/app/pythonpath
  - ./superset:/app/superset
  - ./superset-frontend:/app/superset-frontend
  - superset_home:/app/superset_home

version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2
    container_name: superset_cache
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  db:
    env_file: docker/.env
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: superset_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  superset:
    env_file: docker/.env
    build: *superset-build
    container_name: superset_app
    command: ["flask", "run", "-p", "8088", "--with-threads", "--reload", "--debugger", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-init:
    build: *superset-build
    container_name: superset_init
    command: ["/app/docker-init.sh"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-node:
    image: node:12
    container_name: superset_node
    command: ["bash", "-c", "cd /app/superset-frontend && npm install -f --no-optional --global webpack webpack-cli && npm install -f --no-optional && npm run dev"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-worker:
    build: *superset-build
    container_name: superset_worker
    command: ["celery", "worker", "--app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app", "-Ofair", "-l", "INFO"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-tests-worker:
    build: *superset-build
    container_name: superset_tests_worker
    command: ["celery", "worker", "--app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app", "-Ofair", "-l", "INFO"]
    env_file: docker/.env
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: localhost
      DATABASE_DB: test
      REDIS_CELERY_DB: 2
      REDIS_RESULTS_DB: 3
      REDIS_HOST: localhost
    network_mode: host
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

volumes:
  superset_home:
    external: false
  db_home:
    external: false
  redis:
    external: false
```

[.env file](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/docker/.env):

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=superset

# database configurations (do not modify)
DATABASE_DB=superset
DATABASE_HOST=db
DATABASE_PASSWORD=superset
DATABASE_USER=superset

# database engine specific environment variables
# change the below if you prefers another database engine
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_DIALECT=postgresql
POSTGRES_DB=superset
POSTGRES_USER=superset
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=superset
#MYSQL_DATABASE=superset
#MYSQL_USER=superset
#MYSQL_PASSWORD=superset
#MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes

# Add the mapped in /app/pythonpath_docker which allows devs to override stuff
PYTHONPATH=/app/pythonpath:/app/pythonpath_docker
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379

FLASK_ENV=development
SUPERSET_ENV=development
SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes
```

I tried to work out this issue from any of the solutions presented in the [official repository](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/8880) but in vain.
How do I resolve this issue and complete the installation?

Comment: Are you using the `master` branch? Seems like it's not waiting for the `db` container to be ready

Comment: Yes, I am using the `master` branch and I waited for more than 30 minutes. It is failing to pull that webpack registry.

Comment: Yeah, but the "database test" error is not related to that, as the `docker-compose.yml` includes a test service named "superset-tests-worker" that uses it (and is probably the source of that message). What is odd is that the `superset_app` failed to connect to the PostgreSQL server, even though the database was up and running. Are you [testing it on a Mac](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#start-with-docker)?

Comment: No, this was tested on Fedora 31. I also tried running the docker installation on Mac and it worked smoothly. It is the Fedora installation that I am concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the containers and images and again build the Apache Superset with docker compose.I generally start the Apache Superset with the below command.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```